# Implement a system of stochastic ODEs using python

Tags: python, ode, stochastic

I want to add noise on a system of ODEs from (Ramos & al. 2021) (Kind of SIR model)

[system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4z8p.png)

I implemented the Milstein scheme on some relevant equation

```py
    # Create Brownian Motion
    np.random.seed(1)
    dS = np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dE=np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dI=np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dIu=np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dDu=np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dHR=np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dHD=np.sqrt(dt) * np.random.randn(tmax)
    dB=[dS,dE,dI,dIu,dDu,dHR,dHD]
    sigma=[0.5,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    #Brief definition of systemf function evaluating the second term at time t for each variant i
    for i in range(nvariants):
        newe = S[0]*(mbetae[i]*E[i] + mbetai[i]*I[i] + mbetaiu[i]*Iu[i] + mbetahr[i]*HR[i] + mbetahd[i]*HD[i])/totalpop
        newi = gammae * E[i]
        newhid = gammai  * I[i]
        newhiu = gammaiu * Iu[i]
        newr= gammahr * HR[i]
        newd = gammahd*HD[i]
        newq = gammaq  * Q[i]
        neweS = neweS + newe
        fE[i] = newe-newi
        fI[i] = newi - newhid
        fIu[i]= (1-theta[i]-omegau)*newhid - newhiu
        fHR[i]= p[i]*(theta[i]-fatrate[i])*newhid - newr
        fHD[i]= fatrate[i] *newhid - newd
        fQ[i] = (1-p[i])*(theta[i]-fatrate[i])*newhid + newr - newq
    fS[0] =  - neweS -(vjRK[int(mt.floor(t))]) #fS.insert(0,-neweS -(vjRK[mt.floor(t)]))
    return [fS, fE, fI, fIu, fHR, fHD, fQ]
    for t in range(delayini,tmax-1):
          fsyseval=systemf(t,states[t],beta[2*t],gamma[2*t],frate[2*t],theta[2*t],p[2*t],omegau[2*t],vjsum)
    #Running the scheme
    for s in range(numstates):
            for i in range(nvariants):
                states[t+1][s][i] =states[t][s][i]+fsyseval[s][i]*dt+sigma[s]*dB[s][t]*states[t][s][i] + 0.5*sigma[s]**2 * states[t][s][i] * (dB[s][t] ** 2 - dt)
```

The problem is when I plot the results of each variable (susceptible-infected ....) the result is very strange and have nothing to do with the deterministic model (I see no fluctuations and the shape is not even close to deterministic one) which is illogic. so, I thought that maybe I didn't implement well the stochastic scheme and I missed something.

Now I want to know if my implementation of stochasticity is correct (if yes why the results show no fluctuation despite the high level of noise)
If no, how can I add the stochastic part correctly ?

I thank you for advance for your help

Comment: Note that the "nice" Milstein method is only valid for systems with one-dimensional Brownian motion. Otherwise you get "cross-correlation integrals" with the corresponding higher-order terms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @LutzLehmann , my basic idea came from this work www.hindawi.com/journals/complexity/2022/4247800/ .  Do i just try the Euler–Maruyama scheme? What your advice to the scheme i can implement to the model?

Comment: Yes. The accuracy order of the method as given likely reduces to Euler-Maruyama, so one can as well leave out the extra terms. Higher order methods do exist, but then also require a higher effort.

Comment: @LutzLehmann even with Euler-Maruyama scheme , i still have illogic shapes(straight lines) when adding noise to some equations (Other than the first equation (S)  that gives fluctuation and logical shapes). Is there any explanation why ?

Comment: Mr @LutzLehmann can you help me?